# Querying multiple fields at a time on a view

Tags: couchbase

I have a scenario wherein in my application a user will be searching by search criterias (say field1, field2, field3 (field 3 is a daterange)).
Field1 is a mandatory search criteria, but fields 2...5 are optional and they can come as combinations through user input.

So I created a single view that emits multiple keys (for all possible combinations that a user can search on).

eg:

```
function (doc, meta) {
if(doc.eventType=='myEvent' && doc.field1){
  if(doc.field2) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field2]);
  }
  if(doc.field3) {
  emit(doc.field1,doc.field3]);
  }
  if(doc.field4) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field4]);
  }
  if(doc.field5) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field5]);
  }
  if(doc.field2 && doc.field3) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field2,doc.field3]);
  }
  if(doc.field2 && doc.field4) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field2,doc.field4]);
  }
  if(doc.field2 && doc.field5) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field2,doc.field5]);
  }
  if(doc.field3 && doc.field4) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field3,doc.field4]);
  }
  if(doc.field3 && doc.field5) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field3,doc.field5]);
  }
  if(doc.field4 && doc.field5) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field4,doc.field5]);
  }
  if(doc.field2 && doc.field3 && doc.field4) {
  emit([doc.field2,doc.field3,doc.field4]);
  }
  if(doc.field2 && doc.field3 && doc.field5) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field2,doc.field3,doc.field5]);
  }
  if(doc.field2 && doc.field4 && doc.field5) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field2,doc.field4,doc.field5]);
  }
  if(doc.field3 && doc.field4 && doc.field5) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field3,doc.field4,doc.field5]);
  }
  if(doc.field2 && doc.field3 && doc.field4 *&& doc.field5) {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field2,doc.field3,doc.field4,doc.field5]);
  }
}
}
```

Is this the correct approach or am I missing something here as the index values generated will be redundant and the index file size grows exponentially.

As I' am very new to Couchbase and based on my limited knowledge I understand that couch base doesn’t allow to search for empty values in a query?
For example, I’ am not able to achieve above using a single emit like:

```
function (doc, meta) {
if(doc.eventType=='myEvent' && doc.field1){
if(doc.field2 && doc.field3 && doc.field4 *&& doc.field5 {
  emit([doc.field1,doc.field2,doc.field3,doc.field4,doc.field5]);
  }
}
```

The index builds fine.

But the problem is with "querying" this index, say for a scenario wherein I have multiple search criteria as above (i.e. user may provide one of them or a combination of them), the querying is not possible through key/keys. Else the option that I could find was N1QL, which seems to still be in a developer preview state, so I assume it’s not production ready.

Is there any other better approach for doing such a search and retrieve, as it is a very common use case and as I come from a Relational DB world I’ am finding it difficult to get this concept, or I’ am not sure if I’ am missing something here, please help me, what I’am looking for is a SQL query on a single view, something like:

— fields provided in the where clause may have 1 or more values. Or they may be empty. This is purely based on search criteria entered by end user

```
select * from view_name where doc.field1="x" and doc.field2 in ("y","z","d") and doc.field3 in ("abc") and Date_column between 2011/02/25 and 2011/02/27 sort by Date_Column desc;
```

Is such an above query and retrieval possible at all with couch base views and couch base client java api.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the wrong approach but I'll work up a full answer for you to explain why. :)

Comment: Thanks theMayer. I tried another approach involving lesser number of emits. Basically I tried limiting the emits, by concatenating the searchable keys and using the "\ufff0" in the end key to do a starts with kind of search. Now my view map looks something like:

Comment: Thanks theMayer. I tried another approach involving lesser number of emits. I tried limiting the emits, by concatenating the searchable keys and using the "\ufff0" in the end key to do a starts with kind of search. Now my view map looks something like:       emit([String(doc.a)+"B"+String(doc.b)+"C"+String(doc.c)+"D"+String(doc.d)],null);
emit([String(doc.a)+"C"+String(doc.c)+"B"+String(doc.b)+"D"+String(doc.d)],null);
emit([String(doc.a)+"D"+String(doc.d)+"C"+String(doc.c)+"B"+String(doc.b)],null); And then my startkey=startkey: ["a”], endkey=["aBb\ufff0"] - something like a 'like%' search.

Comment: You are correct that N1QL is not production ready. It will be baked into Couchbase directly in the next major release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the short answer to your question is "this is the incorrect approach." Let me elaborate on this a bit by first giving some background and then pointing you in the right direction.

First, it should be understood that Couchbase is designed to be a very high performance storage and retrieval engine. It is not designed to be a highly searchable full-text database.  In your first sentence, you say

> my application a user will be searching by search criterias

Therefore, this leads to the thought that Couchbase may be ill-adapted for your scenario. I say *may* because Couchbase generally performs well under just about any scenario, but it may require a bit of finagling (a technical term) on your part to get there.

You astutely point out that the approach you have taken is not scalable (to emit every combination of possible values in your data). I would take that a step further. **Not only is it not scalable, but you will actually be using the least-performing feature of Couchbase to satisfy the needs of your application.** Couchbase indexes are disk-based, and while they are fast, they do not share the multi-node memory-based access that is afforded by the memcached-backed vBucket storage mechanism in Couchbase, nor do they offer immediate consistency or any other useful feature of the main Couchbase platform.

Therefore, you are indeed faced with the prospect of choosing another path.  Here are some possible alternatives:

1. **Use a SQL database**: this option is self-explanatory. You get the benefits and drawbacks of SQL.
2. **[Application-side Joins](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html):** with this approach, your application is tolerant of stale indexes and having only reasonably up-to-date results in the searches (reasonable being 1-5 minutes, average worst-case scenario).  You create a separate index for each of the fields you are interested. Then, when the query comes up, you look for intersections among the indices in your data abstraction layer.  For example,

```
    select * from view_name 
    where doc.field1="x"
      and doc.field2 in ("y","z","d") 
      and doc.field3 in ("abc") 
      and Date_column between 2011/02/25 and 2011/02/27
    sort by Date_Column desc;
```

this actually requires four separate indices. In your application, search by the most restrictive indices first, then look in the remaining indices to build your result set, finally sorting the output and sending to the client. You do the work that a SQL database would ordinarily do, but you are using Couchbase so it is super-fast and you don't get any of the magic crap that SQL databases will give you.

3. **Use [N1QL](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/n1ql-dp3/n1ql-intro.html):** this is a sql-based query language built on top of Couchbase. Under the hood, it does something similar to option 2, but does it all for you.
4. **Use [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/):** this is one of the best full-text search noSql data stores out there. It is architeched very similar to Couchbase, except instead of memory-based access, Elasticsearch uses Lucene indexing to achieve very fast full-text search. Use this where you have complex, multi-property documents that you want high-performing searches for a limitless set of queries.  Couchbase even has a [plugin](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-elastic-search/) that dumps data over to an Elasticsearch cluster, so you can have the benefits of both platforms with very little effort.

**Option 4 is probably your best option under any scenario, but it is up to you to weigh the pros and cons of your specific use-case to determine the best path forward.**